# Ubuntu FTP fails to get/mget file for "not found" but !ls sees it

Tags: ftp

I am using the ftp client on Ubuntu 10.04-64.  After connecting and navigating to my upload and source destinations, I can

```
!ls a-long-filename
```

and even

```
!ls a-long-filename-fragm*
```

and both find the files I want to upload.

However, when I

```
get a-long-filename
```

or

```
mget a-long-filename-fragm*
```

both return to the **ftp>** prompt without doing anything.

I have managed to upload other wildcard files from/to the same place using

```
mget a-different-filena*
```

Why can **ls** see the files but **get/mget** cannot?

Comment: FYI:  the real filenames look like XX-City-in-yyyymmdd-hhmmss-000123456.  In otherwords, CompanyAbbrev - City - INcoming - sortedDate - militaryTime - itemNumber.tar.gz.

Comment: mget is for downloads, try mput for upload